# Как передать в API-запросе группировку по странице входа?

Tags: yandex-metrika-api

Нужно снимать статистику через API по странице входа(ещё группировка `ym:s:searchEngine`). В документации она указана как dimensions (группировки). Но запрос с

`dimensions =  "ym:s:startURLPath=='/igrushki/'"`
(только encoded), не работает и возвращает ошибку `invalid_parameter`.
Если подставлять этот же атрибут в фильтры, то данные возвращаются, но результаты не соответствуют отчёту в метрике.

Как заставить заработать страницу входа?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, и заключалась в том, что в рамках фильтрации нужно было использовать оператор "содержит подстроку" (=@), вместо строгой фильтрации оператором "=="

То есть, в итоге должно выглядеть так:
`filters =  "ym:s:startURLPath=@'/igrushki/'"` Разумеется, encoded.